# how does this recursive function work? to merge sort two singly linked lists

Tags: c++, function, sorting, recursion, singly-linked-list

I've found this recursive function in C++ on geeksforgeeks.org, to merge and sort two singly linked lists, I used netbeans to debug this code but still I can't get the clear idea behind the function of this code. also I've seen similar code stackoverflow but with no explanation about the way it works. my question is about the idea behind it and the way it works where the sufficient explanation here also will help others with the same question.

debugged the code on netbeans to understand the work flow of the code

```
//Merges two given lists in-place. This function 
// mainly compares head nodes and calls mergeUtil() 

Node *merge(Node *h1, Node *h2) 
 { 
if (!h1) 
    return h2; 
if (!h2) 
    return h1; 

// start with the linked list 
// whose head data is the least 
if (h1->data < h2->data) 
{ 
    h1->next = merge(h1->next, h2); 
    return h1; 
} 
else
{ 
    h2->next = merge(h1, h2->next); 
    return h2; 
 } 
}
```

this function should return one sorted linked list

Comment: Do some Google searching on "proof by induction". It's a mathematical concept, but it  applies here perfectly. Once you've read and understood how proof by induction works, you should be able to understand this recursive function perfectly: presume that this function returns a sorted list. That's your starting point. This function returns a sorted list. You accept this fact, for granted. Now, go through this simple function, line by line, using the basic principles of proof by induction that you've just learned.

Comment: linking [Mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) or [Structural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) would've been helpful

Answer (score 1):

I added comments to the code. I also changed the if from < to <= in case this was being used for a merge sort, where if h1->data == h2->data, you'd want h1 first for stability. Keep in mind that the two lists are already sorted, this function is just merging them.

The function recursively follows the two lists, skipping past smaller nodes, until it reaches the end of one of the lists, at which point it sets the end of that list to the remainder of the other list and then returns back up the chain of recursive calls, working its way backwards along the lists, setting the smaller nodes next pointers to merge the lists from back to front. This is an inefficient way of merging lists, since it consumes O(n) stack space due to recursion on every node, but it's probably meant as a learning exercise, not to be efficient.

```
// initial input parameters, h1 and h2 each point to already sorted lists
Node *merge(Node *h1, Node *h2) 
{
    if (!h1)                                // if h1 empty
        return h2;                          //  return h2
    if (!h2)                                // if h2 empty
        return h1;                          //  return h1

    if (h1->data <= h2->data)               // if h1->data <= h2->data
    {
        h1->next = merge(h1->next, h2);     //  h1->next = smaller of {h1->next, h2}
        return h1;                          //  return h1
    }
    else                                    // else h1->data > h2->data
    {
        h2->next = merge(h1, h2->next);     //  h2->next = smaller of {h1, h2->next}
        return h2;                          //  return h2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe taking an example is the best way to understand how recursive algorithms work. Let's use these two sample linked lists as an example:

- `{13, 24, 74}`
- `{34, 72, 95}`

Notice that both of them are sorted, since that's a requirement by the [algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-lists-place/):

> Given two sorted lists, merge them so as to produce a combined sorted list

I have compiled a trace of how this turns out:

- Arrow are execution order
- Each line is a stack frame. In particular, the line on the left is before recursive call for `merge`, and the right is its result after.

[image: Execution order]

Notice the following as well:

- On each arrow on the left, the smaller element from start of the nodes disappears
- on the way back, that smaller element gains sorted order of elements on the other side. On the very end we return the list that just gained the other one in a sorted form, namely: {13, 24, 34, 72, 74, 95}